# How can we calculate the Euler-lagrange equations?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, image-processing, inverse-problems, total-variation

In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09605.pdf \
let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 1$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain with boundary $\partial \Omega$, $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an $L^2(\Omega)$ function (given datum), $K: L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ be a bounded linear operator, and $X$ be a Banach space. Then a standard regularized variational model is given by
$$
\min _{u \in X_{a d} \subseteq X} J(u):=\frac{1}{2}\|K u-f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\lambda\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|,
$$
where $X_{a d}$ is a closed, convex, nonempty admissible set which is contained in the solution space $X$, and $u$ is the solution that we want to reconstruct or recover.\
the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations for (2.2) are: Find $u \in X_{a d} \subset X$ such that
$$
\left\langle-\lambda \operatorname{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\right)+K^*(K u-f), \hat{u}-u\right\rangle_{X^{\prime}, X} \geq 0, \quad \forall \hat{u} \in X_{a d}
$$
**How this variational derivative is calculated ?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you understand how the variational derivative is calculated or is the problem just in how the optimality conditions are written?

Comment: I want to know how the variational derivative is calculated

Answer (score 0):

We start with $$J[u] = \frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega (Ku-f)^2 + \lambda \sqrt{\nabla u\cdot\nabla u}~dx.$$
We now perturb this functional to the value $J[u+\epsilon v]$ and collect all the terms linear in $\epsilon$. This is the directional derivative which we will then manipulate into the functional derivative. I will skip some algebra and basic calculus steps to illustrate the main point.

$$
J[u+\epsilon v] = J[u] + \epsilon \int_\Omega Kuv + uKv + \lambda \frac{\nabla u\cdot \nabla v}{\|\nabla u\|}~dx + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).
$$
The last term in the integrand is obtained by differentiating $\sqrt{\nabla u\cdot\nabla u}$ with respect to $u$. The directional derivative is then
$$
\delta J[u]v = \int_\Omega (Ku-f)Kv + \lambda \frac{\nabla u\cdot \nabla v}{\|\nabla u\|}~dx.
$$
If we apply Green's identity (or divergence theorem) to the second term, we have
$$
\delta J[u]v = \int_\Omega (Ku-f)Kv - \lambda \mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\|\nabla u\|}\right)v~dx + \oint_{\partial\Omega} v \frac{\nabla u\cdot \hat{n}}{\|\nabla u\|}~ds.
$$
For optimality, we can restrict $u$ to having homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions so that this boundary term disappears. Our directional derivative can now be written using a duality pairing as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\delta J[u]v &= \langle Ku-f, Kv \rangle -\lambda \left\langle \mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\|\nabla u\|}\right), v\right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle K^* (Ku-f) - \lambda\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\nabla u}{\|\nabla u\|}\right), v \right\rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$
If we write $v = \hat{u}-u$ and require that this directional derivative is positive ($J$ is increasing) in any feasible direction, then we obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification